# Proof Under Fixed Point Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

My defintion of fixed point theorem (FPT)

> If there exists an interval $[a, b]$ such that $\forall x \in [a, b], \: g(x) \in [a, b]$ AND $\forall x \in [a, b], \: g'(x) \leq L \lt 1$, then $g(x)$ has a unique fixed point $\zeta \in [a, b]$.

Assume the conditions and result of FPT for a function $g(x)$ with interval $[a, b]$ (i.e., for any $x_0 \in [a, b]$ and iterating $x_{k+1} = g(x_k)$ for $k = 0, 1, \: ...$ we get $lim_{k \to \infty} x_k = \zeta$)

Let $g(c) = c'$ for some $c \in [a, b]$, then we have
$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
c' - x_{k+1} &= g(c) - g(x_k)\\
             &= g(\alpha_k)(c - x_k) \quad \text{By MVT for some} \: \alpha_k \in [x_k, c]
\end{alignat}
$$

Since $\forall x \in [a, b], \: g'(x) \leq L \lt 1$, it follows that
$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
0 \leq |c' - x_{k+1}| &\leq L|c - x_k|\\
                      &\leq L^2|\beta_{k-1} - x_{k-1}|\\
                      &\leq L^3|\beta_{k-2} - x_{k-2}|\\
                      &\leq \cdots\\
                      &\leq L^{k+1}|\beta_0 - x_0|\\
\end{alignat}
$$

Where each $\beta_{i+1} = g(\beta_i)$ for some $\beta_i \in [a, b]$ and $g(\beta_{k-1}) = c$ for some $\beta_{k-1} \in [a, b]$. With squeeze theorem, we have
$$
\begin{alignat}{2}
                          &\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |c' - x_{k+1}| = 0\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad &\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |c'| = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |x_{k+1}|\\
\Longleftrightarrow \quad &|c'| = \zeta
\end{alignat}
$$

This does not make sense since it means we can choose any $c' \in [a, b]$ and it will be the unique fixed point $\zeta \in [a,b]$. **Where does this proof go wrong?**

Comment: If $c' \neq \zeta$, the construction of the $\beta_i$ can only continue for a finite number of steps. So the conclusion that $x_k \to \zeta$ is false.

Comment: Right, we cannot guarantee $\beta_i$ is defined for an infinite number of steps. Even for a simple example $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ with interval $[-1, 1]$ we choose $c = 0.8 \in [-1, 1]$ so $g(c) = g(0.8) = c' = 0.4$ but we cannot find a $\beta_{k-1} \in [a, b]$ such that $g(\beta_{k-1}) = 0.8$ since the range of $g(x)$ on $[-1, 1]$ is limited to $[-0.5, 0.5]$.

Comment: @copper.hat In a similar fashion, would every $c, c'$ continue for a finite number of steps unless $c = c' = \zeta$?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: @copper.hat My example regarding constructing $\beta_i$ or my question?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean vy $c,c'$ continuing.

Comment: I was asking if every $c \neq \zeta$ we choose on $[a, b]$ as a starting point will fail in a similar way to my $g(x) = \frac{1}{2}x$ example due to not being able to construct $\beta_i$ indefinitely since $\beta_i$ will eventually be outside the interval $[a, b]$.